# Reduce the size of XPS in WPF

Tags: wpf, size, xps

I am creating an XPS Document using XPSDocumentWriter and The XPS document contains charts. Currently the file size of XPS are too big, Is there any way to reduce the size of the XPS Documents. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify *CompressionOption.Maximum* in the XpsDocument constructor.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
Package package = Package.Open(memoryStream, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
string pack = "pack://temp.xps";
PackageStore.AddPackage(new Uri(pack), package);
XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, pack);
```